# Autostart/shutdown sripts not running on windows 10 bat

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a simple script in a.bat:

```
@echo off

echo Date: %date% >> C:\Users\Anon\Desktop\start.txt
```

which I want to run at the system start, and copy of that file, which I want to run at system shutdown.
I've added these files to gpedit.msc->scripts->autostart/shutdown, but non of them works.
Why is that? How can I manage it to work?

Comment: Where did you edit those scripts? The right section would be Windows Settings > Scripts > Shutdown/Startup

Comment: I've added them to gpedit.msc->start/shutdown

Comment: I cant find 'windows settings/scripts'

Comment: Task Scheduler provides options to run something at system startup and shutdown...

Comment: I see only startup, no shutdown tab

Answer (score 1):

More complex, but pure batch solution (working here in windows 8)

> You may need to edit some default values

```
@echo off

rem get arguments: these will be flushed to log file
set "action=%*"

rem log file name
set "logFile=%~dpn0.log"

rem check for delete keyword.
if /i "%~1" EQU "delete" (
  call:deleteScripts && exit/B 0 || (echo/ Scripts deleted: Failed & exit/B 1)
) else (
  call:testScripts || (echo/ Scripts created: Failed & exit/B 1)
)

rem language independent time
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic os get localdatetime /value') do set "Tm=%%a"

set "timeStamp=%Tm:~0,4%-%Tm:~4,2%-%Tm:~6,2% %Tm:~8,2%:%Tm:~10,2%:%Tm:~12,2%"

if not exist "%logFile%" (
  (
    echo/----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    echo/----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    echo/
    echo/Log registry [%~dpnx0]
    echo/
  )
)>>"%logFile%"

echo(%timeStamp% %action%>>"%logFile%"

exit/B

rem delete registry keys.
:deleteScripts
set "baseKey=HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy\Scripts"
set "machKey=HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy\State\Machine\Scripts"
reg delete "%baseKey%\Startup\0" /F >NUL 2>&1
reg delete "%machKey%\Startup\0" /F >NUL 2>&1
reg delete "%baseKey%\Shutdown\0" /F >NUL 2>&1
reg delete "%machKey%\Shutdown\0" /F >NUL 2>&1
echo/ Scripts deleted: Success
exit/B 0

rem check registry keys. if they don't exist create them
:testScripts
set/a msg=0
set "baseKey=HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy\Scripts"
set "machKey=HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Group Policy\State\Machine\Scripts"
reg query "%baseKey%\Startup\0">NUL 2>&1 || (call:createScript "Startup" || exit/B 1)
reg query "%machKey%\Startup\0">NUL 2>&1 || (call:createScript "Startup" || exit/B 1)
reg query "%baseKey%\Shutdown\0">NUL 2>&1 || (call:createScript "Shutdown" || exit/B 1)
reg query "%machKey%\Shutdown\0">NUL 2>&1 || (call:createScript "Shutdown" || exit/B 1)
if %msg% equ 1 echo/ Scripts created: Success
exit/B 0

:createScript
set/a msg=1
setlocal
set "scriptKey=%~1"
set "logMessage=Computer %%COMPUTERNAME%% [%~1]"

rem needed for creating registry keys
set "scriptName=%~dpnx0"

rem English users
set "GP_Name=Local group policy" & rem set "GP_Name=Local Computer policy"
rem Spanish users
rem set "GP_Name=Directiva de grupo local" & rem set "GP_Name=Directiva Equipo local"

reg add "%baseKey%\%scriptKey%\0" /V "GPO-ID" /T REG_SZ /D "LocalGPO" /F >NUL 2>&1 || (EndLocal & exit/B 1)
reg add "%baseKey%\%scriptKey%\0" /V "SOM-ID" /T REG_SZ /D "Local" /F >NUL 2>&1 || (EndLocal & exit/B 1)
reg add "%baseKey%\%scriptKey%\0" /V "FileSysPath" /T REG_SZ /D "C:\\Windows\\System32\\GroupPolicy\\Machine" /F >NUL 2>&1 || (EndLocal & exit/B 1)
reg add "%baseKey%\%scriptKey%\0" /V "DisplayName" /T REG_SZ /D "%GP_Name%" /F >NUL 2>&1 || (EndLocal & exit/B 1)
reg add "%baseKey%\%scriptKey%\0" /V "GPOName" /T REG_SZ /D "%GP_Name%" /F >NUL 2>&1 || (EndLocal & exit/B 1)
reg add "%baseKey%\%scriptKey%\0" /V "PSScriptOrder" /T REG_DWORD /D "00000001" /F >NUL 2>&1 || (EndLocal & exit/B 1)

reg add "%baseKey%\%scriptKey%\0\0" /V "Script" /T REG_SZ /D "%scriptName:\=\\%" /F >NUL 2>&1 || (EndLocal & exit/B 1)
reg add "%baseKey%\%scriptKey%\0\0" /V "Parameters" /T REG_SZ /D "%logMessage%" /F >NUL 2>&1 || (EndLocal & exit/B 1)
reg add "%baseKey%\%scriptKey%\0\0" /V "IsPowershell" /T REG_DWORD /D "00000000" /F >NUL 2>&1 || (EndLocal & exit/B 1)
reg add "%baseKey%\%scriptKey%\0\0" /V "ExecTime" /T REG_BINARY /D "00000000000000000000000000000000" /F >NUL 2>&1 || (EndLocal & exit/B 1)

reg add "%machKey%\%scriptKey%\0" /V "GPO-ID" /T REG_SZ /D "LocalGPO" /F >NUL 2>&1 || (EndLocal & exit/B 1)
reg add "%machKey%\%scriptKey%\0" /V "SOM-ID" /T REG_SZ /D "Local" /F >NUL 2>&1 || (EndLocal & exit/B 1)
reg add "%machKey%\%scriptKey%\0" /V "FileSysPath" /T REG_SZ /D "C:\\Windows\\System32\\GroupPolicy\\Machine" /F >NUL 2>&1 || (EndLocal & exit/B 1)
reg add "%machKey%\%scriptKey%\0" /V "DisplayName" /T REG_SZ /D "%GP_Name%" /F >NUL 2>&1 || (EndLocal & exit/B 1)
reg add "%machKey%\%scriptKey%\0" /V "GPOName" /T REG_SZ /D "%GP_Name%" /F >NUL 2>&1 || (EndLocal & exit/B 1)
reg add "%machKey%\%scriptKey%\0" /V "PSScriptOrder" /T REG_DWORD /D "00000001" /F >NUL 2>&1 || (EndLocal & exit/B 1)

reg add "%machKey%\%scriptKey%\0\0" /V "Script" /T REG_SZ /D "%scriptName:\=\\%" /F >NUL 2>&1 || (EndLocal & exit/B 1)
reg add "%machKey%\%scriptKey%\0\0" /V "Parameters" /T REG_SZ /D "%logMessage%" /F >NUL 2>&1 || (EndLocal & exit/B 1)
reg add "%machKey%\%scriptKey%\0\0" /V "ErrorCode" /T REG_DWORD /D "00000000" /F >NUL 2>&1 || (EndLocal & exit/B 1)
reg add "%machKey%\%scriptKey%\0\0" /V "ExecTime" /T REG_BINARY /D "00000000000000000000000000000000" /F >NUL 2>&1 || (EndLocal & exit/B 1)
EndLocal
exit/B 0
```

Save it as `your_name.bat` file and execute once without arguments. It will create the `starting and shutting down scripts` in the `Local policy group`. You may execute `your_name.bat delete` to delete the scripts.

> Be aware that if you have already set an starting and/or shutting down
>   script, they may be overwritten.
>
> You need administrative rights to `execute registry operations`, but
>   if you're able to open `gpedit.msc` this won't be your case

Once you have setup your scripts you can remove all the `if /i "%~1 ...` section and `all the subroutines` so the script would be simple.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment, type in gpedit.msc and navigate to Windows Settings > Scripts > Startup/Shutdown.

Check the picture to understand where I am at.[image: Scripts - gpedit.msc]

Comment: that's what I made bro. I added scripts to startup and shutdown there, and nothing seems to work